# Handling errors within custom SWR hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, swr

I've written a custom hook that uses SWR to retrieve data from my API whilst setting the 'Authentication' header for the request.

The hook is working fine for all successful requests but I want to be able to handle failed requests (400 status codes).

I'm able to access the status code with the result from `const res = await fetch(url` but how do I return the error in the `error` parameter to the caller of the hook?

```
import useSWR from 'swr';

export default function useAPI(path) {
  const auth = useAuth();

  const { data, error, isValidating, mutate } = useSWR(
    !path ? null : `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}${path}`,

    async (url) => {
      const res = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.user.token}`,
          accept: 'application/json',
        },
      });

      return res.json();
    }
  );
  return { data, error, isValidating, mutate };
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [SWR Error Handling](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/error-handling) documentation:

> If an error is thrown inside fetcher, it will be returned as `error` by the hook.

In your case, you can simply handle to `400` status code response in the fetcher and throw an error after the handling is done.

```js
const { data, error, isValidating, mutate } = useSWR(
    !path ? null : `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}${path}`,
    async (url) => {
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.user.token}`,
                accept: 'application/json'
            }
        });

        if (res.statusCode === 400) {
            // Add your custom handling here

            throw new Error('A 400 error occurred while fetching the data.'); // Throw the error
        }

        return res.json();
    }
);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - that works great.  Just for reference for anyone else, I trap the error like this:

const { data, error } = useAPI(`/equipment/${id}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Handle error
  }, [error]);